# WordPress custom query post-format

Tags: php, wordpress

I have written easy snippet for random post link:

```
function ex_get_random_post_link ()
{
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'rand'
        );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    $query->the_post();
    return get_permalink();
}
```

but i want to get only post with none post format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use the Post Formats for any of my wordpress sites, so I cannot test this code, but try this:

```
function ex_get_random_post_link ()
{
  $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => true,
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
       array(
         'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
         'field' => 'slug',
         'terms' => 'post-format-quote'
       )
      )
    );

  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  $query->the_post();
  return get_permalink();
}
```

I'm not sure how to get "None" for the post format, but the line:

```
'terms' => 'post-format-quote'
```

is where you would change what post format you are using.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/post-formats
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/48901/only-get-posts-of-certain-post-formats